# How to charge user when signing up for free trial in Android Play Billing Library?

Tags: android, play-billing-library

From the official docs (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions), when the user signs up for a free trial, he should add a payment method and after the trial ends, he will be charged. Because of this, I am seeing a lot of people signing up for the trial and canceling the payment at the end of trial. Is there any way to collect payment, right after the user starts the free trial? I want to receive the payment first, when the user cancels the free trial, he should get his money back. Is it possible with Play billing library? Or is there any other way to fix the problem?